# The instance of object type IDocumentClient always null :"No service for type 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.IDocumentClient' has been registered"

Tags: c#

I don't understant why I can't assign a object type IDocumentClient to BuildServerProvider() of IDocumentClient.

Here is the code

```
services.Configure<List<DocumentDbCollection>>(Configuration.GetSection("RepositorySettings"));
services.Configure<List<PushSettings>>(Configuration.GetSection("PushSettings"));

var cosmosSettings = Configuration.GetSection("DocumentDb");

var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var loggerFactory = provider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
var documentClient = provider.GetRequiredService<IDocumentClient>(); // Here crash          
var repositoryOptions = provider.GetService<IOptions<List<DocumentDbCollection>>>(); // Name, partitionKey and offer atributes

services.AddSingleton<NotificationKeyRepository>(new NotificationKeyRepository(loggerFactory, documentClient, repositoryOptions, cosmosSettings));
```

It's like the service always null and I can't assign something null. I saw other examples that they done like this, so what is my fault?

https://prnt.sc/q292rv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if someone see this post I am going to say what happening. When we use `GetService`we are creating a new service in the scoped, but if we dont configure before the object is going to be `null`. So, befero this I configured before and introduce the client settings(remembre that IDOcumentClient is a interface and inside is the client object).